# Programmatically running "Quick Deploy"

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, quick-deploy

After successfully completing a `checkOnly` deployment, is it possible to programmatically run the "Quick Deploy" action?

**Example:**

`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d dist/my-pkg -w 5000 -c`

[image]

I don't see anything via the metadata API, but maybe there is a less "official" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `--validatedeployrequestid` or `-q` flag for `force:mdapi:deploy`

> -q, --validateddeployrequestid=validateddeployrequestid                           request ID of the validated deployment to run a Quick Deploy

To run quick deploy of a recently validated package, use -q with the validated ID.

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -q <validationRequestId> -w -1
```

Also in Metadata API you can use [`deployRecentValidation()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deployRecentValidation.htm) method

Comment: epic! Not sure how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

You could script this by re-directing the validation deploy command output to a text file using "tee".

The text file would contain the Salesforce Deploy ID.

Then, you can just extract the ID from the text file using shell commands and use the ID in the -q flag for a quick deploy.